# Add to favorite from front to end with JavaScript and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I created a add to favorite button. When it's clicked, I want to send datas of the item to the server side before update a Mongo database.

My front code:

```
//save button
let saveBtn = document.getElementById('save-btn')
if(saveBtn) {
    saveBtn.onclick = () => {
        let urlSave = window.location.href;
        let marqueSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__content--marque').textContent;
        let smSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__content--sm2').textContent;
        let typeSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__content--type').textContent;
        let precisionSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__content--precision').textContent;
        let yearsSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__content--yi').textContent;
        let coteSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__content--cote-actual').textContent;
        let imgSave = document.querySelector('.maincar__image').src;

        let parameters = { urlSave: urlSave, marqueSave: marqueSave, smSave: smSave, typeSave: typeSave, precisionSave: precisionSave, yearsSave: yearsSave, coteSave: coteSave, imgSave: imgSave };

        $.get('/save', parameters, () => {
            console.log("Go!");
        })
}};
```

But I have an error in the console: `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:3000/save?urlSave=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapp%2Fac-16-70-coupe-1936-1939&marqueSave=AC&smSave=16%2F70&typeSave=Coup%C3%A9&precisionSave=&yearsSave=1936-1939&coteSave=90%E2%80%AF000%20%E2%82%AC&imgSave=https%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fccv%2Fimage%2Fupload%2F10019.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

EDIT: Now, with this code on the server side:

```
router.get('/save', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    let marqueSave = req.query.marqueSave;
    console.log(marqueSave)
})
```

Nothing happened.

Comment: looks like you dont have a `app.get('/save', ...)` setup, maybe you're after using `$.post` instead.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I added a route and nothing appears (I edited my question)

Comment: do you have any basePath set? how is that router being used? 404 means server is working but the route was not found :(, so maybe you're doing app.use('/save', router) when adding and the rpath is actully `/save/save`. dunno just guessing

Comment: No, my app.use is `app.use('/', save)` and these routes work well for my other pages.